# Insert data from text file to sql

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Form That Import Text File then need to Insert if new records are there in the text file.Update if there are any changes in the already existing field. The code below Read Text File then display to Message box . The Problem is need to insert the following data into my database.

Data.Txt

```
dada|dsda|dsds|dsfd
dsfsdfds|dsfsddsdssdfds|dsds|temp
```

In the Database must be

```
 Name      Address           Age     Sex
 dada      dsda             dsds     dsfd
 dsfsdfds  dsfsddsdssdfds   dsds     temp
```

Code: Read Txt File

```
   TextReader tr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text);

        string line;
         while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

        string[] parts = line.Split('|');


            foreach (string part in parts)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(part);
            }
```

Code: Insert Statment

```
       string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Info(Name,Address,Age,Sex) select '" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text +"','" + textBox4.Text +"'  ";
         SQLcode.DoInsert(sql1);
```

Comment: What problems are you having accessing your database from c#?

Comment: I dont have a problem accessing my database sir . my problem sir is i dont know how to incorporate my insert statement to my for each code that insert data to my database.

Comment: Then I suggest you do some research. There are a large number of resources available to you. This comes across as you asking someone to do your work for you.

Comment: You googled those code snippets, dumped them in your question and now expect us to make it work? Because those snippets seems totally unrelared with each other. On the [Skeet Test](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) this question scores below par.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you didn't enough research on this topic. Try the following code.

```
      TextReader tr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text);

      string line;
      while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
          string[] parts = line.Split('|');
         if(parts.Count() == 4)
          {
            string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Info(Name,Address,Age,Sex) select '" + parts[0] + "','" + parts[1]  + "','" + parts[2]  +"','" + parts[3]  +"'  ";
          SQLcode.DoInsert(sql1);
          }
          else
          {
            // values are more than specified columns.
          }
      }
```

NB: I suggest doing more reading on this subject and see how your can improve your design and code.

Comment: Sir How can I count the total column in my text file during import?

Comment: Before writing the code you should know the file structure. Coming back to your question, if you wanna know how many columns a line contains you can check the number of element in parts array.. ie. parts.Count

Comment: I see, did my comment and code  help or you need further assistant?

Comment: I have a question again sir . how can I create validation that need the parts = column in my database.

Comment: The columns you specified in insert statement will be the ones controling number of columns. Since you speciefied 4 columns then it will mean the number of element in parts will be 4. I'll edit the code, please check if thats what you want.

Comment: Sir @Bayeni How can i count the insert data and invalid data

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the table by

alter table add constraint foreign key (column name) references table where key is(column name)